# Running the StartChaosAsync method seems to have no apparent effect on the Service Fabric cluster

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

I am looking to utilise the chaos testing functionality that comes with Service Fabric. I have setup my code as described in the document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-controlled-chaos

The problem I am experiencing is that I almost always see no fault events exhibited by my cluster. Below is an example of the console output that I get running the chaos sample code;

```html
[StartedEvent], Timestamp=03/02/2017 16:32:21
ChaosParameters: maxClusterStabilizationTimeout=00:00:30, waitTimeBetweenFaults=00:00:20, waitTimeBetweenIterations=00:00:30, maxConcurrentFaults=3, timeToRun=01:00:00, enableMoveReplicas=True, Context:
ClusterHealthPolicy=ClusterHealthPolicy: MaxPercentUnhealthyNodes=0, MaxPercentUnhealthyApplications=0, ConsiderWarningAsError=True


[ExecutingFaultsEvent], Timestamp=03/02/2017 16:32:26
0 Faults:

[ExecutingFaultsEvent], Timestamp=03/02/2017 16:33:00
0 Faults:

[ExecutingFaultsEvent], Timestamp=03/02/2017 16:33:33
0 Faults:

[ExecutingFaultsEvent], Timestamp=03/02/2017 16:34:06
0 Faults:

[ExecutingFaultsEvent], Timestamp=03/02/2017 16:34:40
0 Faults:

[ExecutingFaultsEvent], Timestamp=03/02/2017 16:35:13
```

Am I missing any configuration?

I get these results against both my local and Azure cluster. I also have tried both C# and PowerShell examples and they both have the same results.

I have only seen this work once (locally) and every [ExecutingFaultsEvent] was Restart a node. Should I see more than one type of faults here as well?

Comment: Can you add the current health of the entities in the cluster as well? With "considerwarningaserror" if there's any warnings then Chaos will consider things unhealthy and not move them.

Comment: I have tried setting "ConsiderWarningsAsError" to true and have confirmed that all my entities are healthy but I still see the same issue every time I run this code. Are there any logs anywhere that I could take a look at to help diagnose this?

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this as I am seeing a similar problem with my azure service fabric cluster?

Comment: Unfortunately no I haven't got the bottom of that yet. Last time I checked it was still an issue.

Comment: This could be because of your cluster configuration as well. If there are no faults possible without affection availability it will not induce any faults. What kind of services do you have on this cluster ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the supplied sample code (and lack of useful samples, generally, in this domain...). In addition, for immediate satisfaction (to see chaos happen without waiting too long...), you need to be more aggressive than the docs sample (which, again, doesn't really work, as you've discovered...).

You are better served to use a *different* overload for the ***ChaosParameters*** constructor...

Try this (replace the sample code's impl with this):

```
            var startTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var stabilizationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.0);
            var timeToRun = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60.0);
            var maxConcurrentFaults = 7;
            var timeBetweenFaults = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
            var timeBetweenIterations = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
            Dictionary<string, string> _context = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            //Aggressive chaos...
            var clusterHealthPolicy = new System.Fabric.Health.ClusterHealthPolicy()
            {
                MaxPercentUnhealthyApplications = 90,
                MaxPercentUnhealthyNodes = 100
            };

            var parameters = new ChaosParameters(
                stabilizationTimeout,
                maxConcurrentFaults,
                true, /* EnableMoveReplicaFault */
                timeToRun,
                _context,
                timeBetweenIterations,
                timeBetweenFaults,
                clusterHealthPolicy);
```

NOTE: I recommend that you do this in a new static async Task-returning function...

Full (working) sample:

```
    public static async Task RunChaos()
    {
        var clusterConnectionString = "localhost:19000";
        using (var client = new FabricClient(clusterConnectionString))
        {
            var startTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var stabilizationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.0);
            var timeToRun = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60.0);
            var maxConcurrentFaults = 7;
            var timeBetweenFaults = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
            var timeBetweenIterations = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
            Dictionary<string, string> _context = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            //Aggressive chaos...
            var clusterHealthPolicy = new System.Fabric.Health.ClusterHealthPolicy()
            {
                MaxPercentUnhealthyApplications = 90,
                MaxPercentUnhealthyNodes = 100
            };

            var parameters = new ChaosParameters(
                stabilizationTimeout,
                maxConcurrentFaults,
                true, /* EnableMoveReplicaFault */
                timeToRun,
                _context,
                timeBetweenIterations,
                timeBetweenFaults,
                clusterHealthPolicy);

            var token = new System.Threading.CancellationToken();

            try
            {
                await client.TestManager.StartChaosAsync(parameters, new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0), token); 
            }
            catch (FabricChaosAlreadyRunningException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An instance of Chaos is already running in the cluster.");
            }

            var filter = new ChaosReportFilter(startTimeUtc, DateTime.MaxValue);

            var eventSet = new HashSet<ChaosEvent>(new ChaosEventComparer());

            while (true)
            {
                var report = await client.TestManager.GetChaosReportAsync(filter);

                foreach (var chaosEvent in report.History)
                {
                    if (eventSet.Add(chaosEvent))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(chaosEvent);
                    }
                }

                // When Chaos stops, a StoppedEvent is created.
                // If a StoppedEvent is found, exit the loop.
                var lastEvent = report.History.LastOrDefault();

                if (lastEvent is StoppedEvent)
                {
                    break;
                }

                Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
        }
    }
```